# error de ruta absoluta al iniciar un script python como servicio con systemctl

Tags: python, ubuntu

quiero ejecutar un script de python como servicio en ubuntu 16.10, el archivo `.service` es el siguiente:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ruta Optima
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=source /home/adminisa/env/bin/activate && 
/home/adminisa/env/bin/python3 /home/adminisa/api.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

el error es en la linea `ExecStart`, que me da como error lo siguiente `Executable path is not absolute`, no se si estoy en un error pero todas las rutas en esa linea son absolutas y no encuentro en donde este mal, ya que si ejecuto esa linea en consola entra al entorno virtual y ejecuta el script, espero puedan aydarme. De antemano gracias

Comment: posiblemente se deba a que no puedes usar `source` en ExecStart si no das ruta absoluta al ejecutable. No sería mejor usar `Environment="FOO=bar baz"` en  tu definición del servicio?

Comment: gracias por responder, no se mucho de servicios, en `Environment="FOO=bar baz"` iria mi entorno virtual? gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si sea la mejor solución, pero lo solucione creando un archivo `sh` con el contenido de la linea `ExecStart`

```
source /home/adminisa/env/bin/activate && 
/home/adminisa/env/bin/python3 /home/adminisa/api.py
```

y modificando esa linea del archivo `.service` con lo siguiente

```
ExecStart=/home/adminisa/archivo.sh
```

Estuve quebrandome la cabeza por algo con solucion muy simple, lo pongo por si alguien mas esta en las mismas y no se le ocurre esto

Comment: Lo más simple es lo que mejor funciona. Buena solución :)